# Php: preg_match return false

Tags: php

That is my `preg_match` code:

```
 if (strlen($str) > 0)
        if (!preg_match('/(http:\/\/www.vbox7.com[^\"]*)/', $str))
            return false;

    return true;

$str = 'http://vbox7.com/play:5ee7f7f6bf';
```

but why always return false?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, the your regex will not detect your URL, because it explicitly looks for the "www" string. Alternately, you can try:

```
preg_match('/(http:\/\/[www.]{0,1}vbox7.com[^\"]*)/', $str)
```

Also, you might want to set your $str at the top, instead of the bottom.